# Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline: Precompiled MD5 Fingerprints don't match

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, pipeline, assets

I'm having a Rails 3.1 rc6 app on Heroku's cedar stack (ruby 1.9.2).

I precompile assets using rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production locally on my development machine.

The problem is the generated md5 fingerprints in the precompiled filenames don't match the ones generated by the rails helpers (like asset_path) in production on Heroku.

Does anyone have a clue why this is? How can I fix it? I can't precompile on Heroku, as they have a read only filesystem.

Comment: I have the same problem... No solution until yet..

Comment: Link to github issue page: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2569

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a stab in the dark, but when I upgraded to rc6 today, this broke in an initializer:

```
if RAILS_ENV == 'production'
```

and was fixed with this:

```
if Rails.env.production?
```

Don't know if that's got anything to do with it.

Comment: Well, that is actually because in Rails 3.1 the deprecated RAILS_ENV has been removed.

Comment: See here for a discussion about the problem: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2569#issuecomment-1830815